# Using 2 Google API keys in same project?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I have a project which I use Google Places API.
For the API key I have now, I have set IP restriction because the API is called in server-side. [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search) and [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) are called in Server and returned to client side.

But the endpoint [Place Photos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/photos), I call in client side, and of course it doesn't work because I have set IP restriction. So, my idea is to create one more production api key which works on client side and set HTTP referrers. Is this Ok? Or should I call all apis in server-side instead?

Comment: TBH i dont think there is any other way to do it.   As far as i know there is no way to ip restrict an api key running client side.  It just wouldn't work.